# What is boundary cosmological constant in boundary Liouville field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, quantum-gravity, boundary-conditions, boundary-terms

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0001012v1), Liouville field theory with conformally invariant boundary is studied. The action is:

$$
\int_{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{4 \pi}\left(\partial_{a} \phi\right)^{2}+\mu e^{2 b \phi}\right) d^{2} x+\int_{\partial \Gamma}\left(\frac{Q k}{2 \pi} \phi+\mu_{B} e^{b \phi}\right) d \xi
$$
where $k$ is extrinsic curvature on boundary, and the parameter $\mu_{B}$ is called "boundary cosmological constant".

However, I am really confused about how to get this boundary cosmological constant $\mu_{B}$ from conformal boundary condition, and what is the relationship between $\mu_{B}$  and $\mu$?

Can anyone show the details of the derivation of $\mu_{B}$?

Comment: For the moment $\mu_B$ is just a parameter in the action. It can take any value and it is not related to $\mu$. If your question is about proving a relation, please state explicitly which relation you want to prove.

Comment: @Sylvain Ribault
 Why do we need to add $\mu_{B}$ to the boundary term?

Comment: Any term in the action that respects the symmetries comes with its own coefficient.